# I want a playbook to install multiple packages on multiple machines

Tags: ansible

eg: I have 5 clients machines and i need to install 5 different packages on all 5 machines

```
192.168.20.5: vsftpd
192.168.30.7:ftp
192.168.45.7:httpd
```

so on
is there any method to iterate both hosts and package names

i have tried iterating using with_items but unable to iterate with hosts

```
- name: installing packages
  yum: name="{{item.name}}" state=present
  when: ansible_hostname== item.host
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please share your playbook so we can take a look at it.

Answer (score 2):

This is a great use case for Ansible [host variables](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/intro_inventory.html#splitting-out-host-and-group-specific-data).  Create a file in `host_vars/` for each of your hosts that looks something like this:

```
packages:
  - vsftpd
```

Then your package install task should look like this:

```
- name: install packages
  package:
    name: "{{ packages }}"
    state: installed
```

This will use the correct value of the `packages` variable for the host on which the task is executing.

---

It looks like your hosts may be serving different *roles*. Instead of the solution I've presented in the first part of this question, you may want to organize your project using Ansible roles (e.g., one for a webserver, one for an ftp server, etc). In this case, information about packages would be linked to a role rather than a specific host, and your playbook would associate roles with hosts.

Comment: but can you suggest other solutions instaed of roles as i wil be dealing with many number of client machine i think i need to include msny playbooks

Comment: I did suggest a solution instead of roles. That was the first part of the answer. I still think that a roles-based configuration would be the better choice.